# laptop overheat after update/install of 18.04 lts from 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04, updates, 18.04, overheating

I had tried to update my 16.04lts to 18.04lts successfully, but right after it requested for a reboot my laptop (Dell Inspiron N5010) simply turned off. I tried turning it on, but right after it tells me of some "OVERHEAT/TEMPERATURE..." it turns off again. I had tried it more than 10x. After a while, I waited for an hour and it turned on. But the weird thing is the laptop becomes literally hot, starting from the touch pad. The fan was also noisy, the sound is very audible, as compare to normal fan noise. To think that there was no open program or files, as I was doing nothing. I never had this issue before in windows and even in 16.04 LTS. What I did is I had re-installed 18.04LTS and overwrite the existing installation. Afterwards, the scenario was still the same. I tried it 2x, to no avail. Now, I am back to 16.04 LTS, and everything is fine. What can I do to use 18.04 LTS without overheat issues?

Answer (score 0):

Please install Ubuntu **18.04.1**. It is more stable compared to 18.04. Also, rather than installing on top of 16.04, have backup of needed items and install 18.04.1 after wiping the hard drive completely. I am sure it will work.

Recently , I upgraded my **16.04.5** to **18.04.1** using `sudo updata-manager -d` and it works like a charm after installation completed.
My Laptop is **HCL Me XITE L55**, 7 years old!

Comment: I may have made a mistake in writing. What I installed is 18.04.1 LTS Version. I did an upgrade from 16.04.4 LTS, but it overheats. I did an overwrite install but it overheats. I did a "something else" installation and deleted all partition and installed 18.04.1 LTS but still it overheats. My laptop is a Dell Inspiron N5010 i3, 3Gb RAM, and I bought it way back 2010. It overheats without doing anything. The fan has a very audible noise.

Comment: My laptop has i3 1st gen processor, x86. Your case seems strange. I tried in AMD platforms also, worked fine.

Comment: I tried "googling" this overheat issue and had found this - " https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1768976 " . I was reading a lot this thread but the terminologies used are not for me. I will just be waiting for a simplified solutions here.

Comment: okay, the bug is confirmed. Lets hope it gets fixed asap.

Comment: any fix for this issue?

Comment: A kind follow up, please. Just now, I had received an 18.04LTS Upgrade warning, I just neglected it, since I am not sure if this overheat issue is already solved or not. Please advise.

Comment: If you want to test again then got for it. If you rolled back to 16.04, then do `sudo update-manager -d` but it will take more than an hour despite good internet connection. Take the backup of your important files before doing so.

Comment: Guess 18.04.1LTS is really not for my laptop. I did an upgrade again,but the laptop fan is continuously running to a point it makes an irritating sound. There is still overheat issues.

Comment: again, I tried an upgrade,but still the fan is really noisy, and the laptop still overheats. any fix yet?